How to create a parent project containing two independent projects in Android Studio
I have two separate Android projects: a camera project and an image editing project. I want to create a new parent project that includes both of these projects and allows them to start independently. Specifically, I want to be able to run the parent project, the camera project, and the editing project separately.
I understand that to run them independently, each project must use the 'com.android.application' plugin instead of 'com.android.library'.
What I Have Tried:
-Created a new parent project.
-Added the camera and editing projects as modules to the parent project.
-Modifying settings.gradle.kts:

    include(":app")
    include(":camera")
    include(":editing")

Adding Dependencies in Parent Project (app) build.gradle.kts:
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":camera"))
    implementation(project(":editing"))
}

However, when I try to run parent project, I encounter the following error:
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Unable to make AAPT link command","sources":[{}],"original":"ERROR: AAPT: ","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Unable to make AAPT link command
     ERROR: AAPT:
...
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Unable to make AAPT link command
...
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Dependent features configured but no package ID was set.

Question:
How can I properly set up a parent project that includes two independent Android projects, allowing each to run separately?
Thank you.

One can only have one app module, which may be the misconception here. You could in best case script settings.gradle.kts and include either the one or the other app module; both at the same time won't work out.
